# I'm trying to store the credit card using cardsAPI on Node.js, but there doesn't seem to be the component in Node Models

Tags: node.js, square

At first, I rename Client to squareClient, then I try to use the cardsAPI as the documentation says, but there's no cardsAPI. I checked in node_models/square, and there's not such a file either. I updated my Square to the latest version

```
async function squareCreateCard(squareCardData ){
  const sqClient = new squareClient({
    accessToken: "XXX HIDDEN XXX",
    environment: Environment.Sandbox,
  });
  try {
    const response = await sqClient.cardsApi.createCard({
      // idempotencyKey: '4935a656-a929-4792-b97c-8848be85c27c',
      // sourceId: 'cnon:uIbfJXhXETSP197M3GB',
      // card: {
      //   cardholderName: 'Amelia Earhart',
      //   billingAddress: {
      //     addressLine1: '500 Electric Ave',
      //     addressLine2: 'Suite 600',
      //     locality: 'New York',
      //     administrativeDistrictLevel1: 'NY',
      //     postalCode: '10003',
      //     country: 'US'
      //   },
      //   customerId: 'VDKXEEKPJN48QDG3BGGFAK05P8',
      //   referenceId: 'user-id-1'
      // }
      idempotencyKey: ObjectID().toString(),
      sourceId: squareCardData.sourceId,
      card: squareCardData.card ,
    });
  
   console.log(response.result);
    return response.result;
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(
      "An error ocurred while creating the card"
    );
    console.error(error);
    throw {
      error: true,
      message: error,
    };
  }
}
```

I have checked and there'seems to not be a .cardsApi, however all the documentation says it should be a cardsApi

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation that you are referencing?

Comment: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/cards-api/create-card

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that documentation is about a REST API endpoint, not a nodeJS function. Have you tried making an API call (with a package like fetch) to that endpoint?

Comment: Thank you so much for replaying, yes, I make the request from the from the front end, the function previously sent is call from Services.Client: 
        `router.post("/squarecreatecard", auth.isAuthed, jsonbody, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {createCardDetails} = req.body;
    const result = await Services.Client.squareCreateCard(createCardDetails);
    return res.status(200).send({result});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred while storing the card");
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});`